# How to ask for "Save Changes?" on Lighthing Component form when user tries to navigate away

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-community

We have a Lightning Community and would like to prompt the user to "Save Changes" if they try to click one of the community's navigational components (home link, or other menu item) but they have unsaved form changes on a custom Lightning component.

Ideally, we'd have a `window.confirm` popup asking if they want to leave without saving their changes, and if they click Cancel, the URL navigation would be aborted.

Is this possible via custom Lighting Components and Lighting Communities, and if so, how? If not, are there any patterns to work around this?

Comment: wouldnt it be easier to keep your form's state in an attribute which is present in a global context of your community and instead display in another component a notification that they have unsaved changes?